# Is using FileOutputStream directly efficient? Why are BufferedWriter and other methods used?

Tags: java, file-handling, fileoutputstream

how to make this more efficient in reference to file handling?
And how to write data in different line? I tried using `signup.nextLine()` but got a *not found* error instead.

```
void SignUp()throws IOException
{
    try{
        FileOutputStream signup = new FileOutputStream("LoginData.txt",true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(signup);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\f***Registeration Desk***\n");
        System.out.print("Username: ");
        String u = sc.next();
        signup.write(u.getBytes());
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        signup.write("-".getBytes());
        signup.write((sc.next()).getBytes());
        System.out.println("\nUser Checked In.\nPress Enter To Continue...");
        System.in.read();   //read() inputs only 1 byte.
        bootLoader();   //My other function         
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Write to the BufferedWriter, not the FOS directly. FileOutputStream does not have a `nextLine()` method.

Comment: @Fildor, how about rest of the stuff? Will it be better to use BufferedWriter instead of FOS?

Comment: The chain is BW->FOS->FileSystem. You write to the begin of the chain so to the BufferedWriter. FileSystem I/O is generally expensive, so you most likely want to use that Buffer instead of writing directly. You can look into Java Documentation for further info on that. You may consider using "try with resources".

Comment: Just saw you are writing bytes. With a BufferedWriter, you can write the Strings directly. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html You may even further wrap the BufferedWriter with a PrintWriter.

Comment: So, Writing in bytes makes the program more performance expensive so we use buffer. Am I correct? And what is the use of PrintWriter?

Comment: "Writing in bytes makes the program more performance expensive so we use buffer" - not exactly. If you want to write Strings, Printwriter through BufferedWriter gives you 1. convenient methods for writing Strings and 2. Buffering so that not every write actually writes through to the FileSystem. You can do all that by yourself, too. It is just a well tested way to do so.